# trial version of Visual studio .NET or visual studio 6

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

Can any body tell me, is it possible to get trail version for Visual studio .NET 2003 or Visual studio 6.0

I searched alot and all the links which i got, was outdated.

Please help, atleast tell me whether it is available or not.

Comment: off course it's outdated, it's technology from almost 10 years old for which there are now much better alternatives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually download it from MSDNAA or Deamspark if you are a student or university member:

http://e5.onthehub.com/WebStore/OfferingsOfMajorVersionList.aspx?ws=5650d4c2-5f9b-e011-969d-0030487d8897&vsro=8&pmv=23c41a99-3ef3-db11-b8b4-0030485a6b08&cmi_mnuMain=bdba23cf-e05e-e011-971f-0030487d8897

As far as I know all other official Microsoft sources were closed.

Comment: I am not part of this university. Is there any way to be part of this university, i tried to register but first i need to give some name for the registration.

Comment: You can find any university near to you that is enrolled in DreamSpark Premium program (formerly MSDN Academic Alliance, MSDNAA). Read http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/DreamSpark_Premium for more information.

Comment: ohh, it seems little bit difficult. Anyways i'll check. Thanks for the info :).

Answer (score 0):

Not available. The free versions ("Visual Studio Express Edition") started in 2005.

Besides, there is little reason to use such outdated versions. Especially for C++, the new versions are far more compliant with recent standards ('03 and '11).